# Login fails at X_GLXCreateContext

Tags: login, gnome-session

Yesterday I installed some updates like I always do, and I noted that there was a new kernel version and a new version of the nvidia driver. Today, the resolution at the login screen was very low and rebooting didn't help. After I type my password, the following shows up in the syslog and after a few seconds I am thrown back to the login screen.

```
Nov 12 21:35:02 Kalle-PC lightdm: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/kalle is already mounted
Nov 12 21:35:02 Kalle-PC org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[4431]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Nov 12 21:35:02 Kalle-PC systemd[1]: Started Session c13 of user kalle.
Nov 12 21:35:03 Kalle-PC org.ayatana.bamf[4647]: bamfdaemon start/running, process 4702
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4799]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC dbus[933]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]:   Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]:   Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]:   Value in failed request:  0x0
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]:   Serial number of failed request:  26
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]:   Current serial number in output stream:  27
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session[4788]: gnome-session-binary[4788]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC gnome-session-binary[4788]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Nov 12 21:35:04 Kalle-PC lightdm[1090]: ** (lightdm:1090): CRITICAL **: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
Nov 12 21:35:06 Kalle-PC acpid: client 4411[0:0] has disconnected
Nov 12 21:35:06 Kalle-PC acpid: client connected from 4936[0:0]
Nov 12 21:35:06 Kalle-PC acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov 12 21:35:06 Kalle-PC systemd[1]: Started Session c14 of user lightdm.
Nov 12 21:35:06 Kalle-PC org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4972]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
```

I already tried `apt-get purge nvidia-*` followed by `apt-get install nvidia-current` and a reboot. This fixed the resolution, but I am stuck with the login error.

Is there anyone out there who might have a clue about what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stuck with the same problem after the last update. It seems, that the current nvidia driver version does not work. I found this posting:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1639180

```
> Downgrade from 304.132 to 304.131:
> - CTRL+ALT+1 to console
> - login
> - sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
> - sudo apt-get autoremove
> - sudo apt-get install nvidia-304=304.131-0ubuntu3
```

Cheers,
Dimi